# Trying to check if a file is there, if not download it

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Hi guys I'm trying to use this simple code to check if a file is there, if not download it. But it will always only display me "Checking for data file".

What could be the reason?

I found the code here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>My App</h2>
    <div id="status"></div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);

//The directory to store data
var store;

//Used for status updates
var $status;

//URL of our asset
var assetURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/master/readme.md";

//File name of our important data file we didn't ship with the app
var fileName = "mydatafile.txt";

function init() {

    $status = document.querySelector("#status");

    $status.innerHTML = "Checking for data file.";

    store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

    //Check for the file. 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);

}

function downloadAsset() {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    console.log("About to start transfer");
    fileTransfer.download(assetURL, store + fileName, 
        function(entry) {
            console.log("Success!");
            appStart();
        }, 
        function(err) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.dir(err);
        });
}

//I'm only called when the file exists or has been downloaded.
function appStart() {
    $status.innerHTML = "App ready!";
}
```

These are only the last lines of output from logcat in android Studio because it would be too much to insert everything in here:

```
10-22 16:46:40.927    2315-2315/? E/PGA﹕ PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_CULL_FACE, assuming size 1
10-22 16:46:40.927    2315-2315/? E/PGA﹕ PgaUtilsParamSize: unsuported param GL_DITHER, assuming size 1

-22 16:47:48.367  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:48:43.477  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:48:48.827   30217-2359/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: ping
10-22 16:48:48.827   30217-2359/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:48:48.847   30217-2360/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: clipboard (with args)
10-22 16:48:48.847   30217-2360/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:49:38.587  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:50:33.697  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:50:42.037   30217-2361/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: ping
10-22 16:50:42.037   30217-2361/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:50:42.257   30217-2362/? W/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ Reached maxLineLength limit while reading the content of a file
10-22 16:50:42.257   30217-2362/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: clipboard (with args)
10-22 16:50:42.267   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1969K, 24% free 6849K/8896K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:50:42.277   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1557K, 24% free 6850K/9004K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-22 16:50:42.287   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1318K, 24% free 6854K/9004K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-22 16:50:42.297   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1230K, 24% free 6851K/9012K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-22 16:50:42.307   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1215K, 24% free 6852K/9012K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:50:42.307   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1161K, 24% free 6858K/9012K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:50:42.317   30217-2362/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1101K, 24% free 6862K/9012K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-22 16:50:42.317   30217-2362/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:51:28.807  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:52:00.027  30100-30111/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7538K, 38% free 12639K/20212K, paused 10ms, total 20ms
10-22 16:52:23.917  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:53:19.027  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:53:26.057   30217-2363/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: ping
10-22 16:53:26.057   30217-2363/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:53:26.077   30217-2364/? W/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ Reached maxLineLength limit while reading the content of a file
10-22 16:53:26.077   30217-2364/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: clipboard (with args)
10-22 16:53:26.097   30217-2364/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1795K, 25% free 6825K/9020K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-22 16:53:26.097   30217-2364/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1489K, 25% free 6824K/9020K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:53:26.117   30217-2364/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1352K, 25% free 6825K/9020K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
10-22 16:53:26.117   30217-2364/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1251K, 25% free 6836K/9020K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:53:26.127   30217-2364/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:54:14.137  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:54:23.877   30217-2365/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: ping
10-22 16:54:23.877   30217-2365/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:54:23.887   30217-2366/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ command: clipboard (with args)
10-22 16:54:23.887   30217-2366/? D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd﹕ response: {"result":"ok"}
10-22 16:54:30.017  29999-30062/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
10-22 16:54:30.017  29999-30062/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ Done.
10-22 16:54:30.017  29999-30062/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ Setting timer for 720seconds
10-22 16:54:30.197  29999-30062/? D/ConnectivityService﹕ handleInetConditionChange: net=1 != default=9 - ignore
10-22 16:55:09.247  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:55:41.237  29999-29999/? I/EntropyMixer﹕ Writing entropy...
10-22 16:56:04.357  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
10-22 16:56:59.467  30178-30897/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 736K, 29% free 2727K/3840K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
```

Comment: "is there" ... is where?

Comment: shouldn't the last function replace "checking for data file" after the file is downloaded?

Comment: What does the console output look like? You should be getting some log statements coming through.

Comment: I inserted the last lines of output, I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Taurus22,
you are likely using the latest version of the compiler. This is a common issue with developer new to Cordova/Phonegap. You have a `whitelist` issue.

### The fix to many common *white-list* problems

The alternative is this quick fix – but know that this *quick fix* removes all needs for `white-list`. This creates a [security issue](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-webview-security-582363/) which you may not want to by pass.

**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml` for **PHONEGAP BUILD ONLY**
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

The long answer is as such:

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #10 **Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.**

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1 and cli-5.2.0. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let's say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. **Depending on your use and the version of Phonegap you are using, the CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. However, there are cases where it is not needed at all. The documentation is confusing for some, please read it carefully.** The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.
>
> Lastly, Raymond Camden in his blog points to a [LARGE change in policy starting with Cordova 5](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5)

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you it works now :)